# Powershell disk management

Tags: windows, powershell, storage

Welcome, I have question about managing disks via Powershell. Is there any possibility to (like in DISKPART)
- change type of disk to dynamic,
- create mirrored disk,
- create raid-5 volume, 
- extend volume 
But is it possible to do it using Powershell? I mean I need to do these things by using Powershell, NOT DISKPART, but can't find any solution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, some diskpart functionality is not implemented in PowerShell. You can make disk online, initialize it, create basic volumes (GPT and MBR). Dynamic disks **can’t be** created using PowerShell. Therefore spanned, striped, mirrored or parity volumes can’t be created without using DISKPART.

Microsoft advertises Storage Spaces instead of “Dynamic disks”. More about pro’s and contra’s  - https://serverfault.com/a/883491/382022

Storage Spaces may be fully managed in PowerShell . Here some articles (mostly for server editions, but same commands for client):

“Managing disk with PowerShell” - https://4sysops.com/archives/managing-disks-with-powershell/

Available cmdlets for Storage Spaces - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storagespaces/?view=winserver2012r2-ps&viewFallbackFrom=win10-ps

“Creating a Storage Pool and a Storage Space” - https://lazywinadmin.com/2013/08/ws2012-storage-creating-storage-pool.html

“Automated storage tiering” - https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/configure-a-resilient-volume-on-windows-server-2016-using-storage-spaces